# Is it possible to compile ffmpeg in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg

Is it possible to compile the sourcecode from ffmpeg in visual studio 2010? Is it difficult?

Just looking for some advice (and instructions) if possible. :-)

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible because ffmpeg makes extensive use of C99 features (with good reason), and MSVC doesn't support nearly enough nook and crannies of the standard.

You can however, use the C library built by MinGW for use with Visual Studio projects.  See the following links for all the information you need:

1. Information about building/using the library on Windows with Visual Studio: http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
2. Downloads: http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/

Answer (score 7):

Apparently someone at Google has written a `C99` to `C89` "downconverter" in part to get `ffmpeg` to compile with `Visual Studio`:

http://blogs.gnome.org/rbultje/2012/09/27/microsoft-visual-studio-support-in-ffmpeg-and-libav/

The tool they wrote is currently only in source code form.  Although that tool is written in `C`, it uses some compiler specific includes, specific to the `Clang` compiler, so you currently need clang to compile it.  I had to get all the pieces to `Clang` (which relies on `llvm`) and compile with `VS2010`.  OK, got that figured out, so now I have the two tools compiled: `c99wrap.exe` and `c99conv.exe`.

The blog does not mention two important things that are mentioned here:

http://libav.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b

First, you have to ensure the `link.exe` you use is the `Visual C linker` and not the `mingw linker`.  Also, the `msvc toolchain` under msys does not yet support shared `DLL` builds, it only supports static lib builds at this time, so --enabled-shared fails to link.

Comment: see also http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b which is the same link

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is possible

> To use FFmpeg SVN libraries with your Microsoft Visual C++ project,
>   you must first make sure your Microsoft Visual C++ build system has
>   the inttypes.h and stdint.h include files.
>
> How do I know if I have those files? Well... unless you already did
>   this and know you have that file, you don't have it. MSVC++ does not
>   adhere to the C99 standard, where that file is specified, so you're on
>   your own here.
>
> Alexander Chemeris was nice enough to make such files for Microsoft
>   Visual C++, so they can be found here
>
> Download latest archive from link above and unpack it to the folder to
>   which you installed FFmpeg's include files. The default path is
>   /usr/local/include, which is, in this guide for Windows,
>   C:\msys\local\include.

[Inttypes C99](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=Inttypes.h)

Comment: good answer--you can use mingw or cross compiled binaries (dll's) and link against them as another option to compiling the whole thing with MSVC

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2013 provides the support for C99 which was missing earlier.  With this ffmpeg can now be built using Visual Studio 2013.  You can read more about the new language/libraries features [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx).

Also, try out Visual Studio 2013 RC [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-2013).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#SEC22) it is not possible.